# Problemas com WHERE IN (muitos registros)

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso montar uma *query* para buscar registros na tabela A, com filtro de registros da tabela B. Algo parecido com:

```
SELECT * FROM tabelaA tblA WHERE tblA.coluna IN (1,2,3,...)
```

Os valores contidos no filtro "IN" são provenientes da tabela B e, em alguns casos, podem ser dezenas ou até centenas.

Dúvidas: Por se tratar de um número indefinido de valores, esta é a forma correta? Se não, qual a melhor abordagem para o caso? Quando o número de valores no filtro for muito grande, pode causar terei problemas com performance no banco?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Tem razão @bigown. É que estou tão corrido que acabei não tendo tempo de testar nenhuma das soluções apresentadas. Farei isso o quanto antes e apontarei a melhor solução. Obrigado por me lembrar!

Answer (score 5):

Provavelmente se você usar um `JOIN` obterá melhor performance. Como há não detalhes não sei se resolveria seu caso, se não resolver, aí o `IN` pode ser a melhor solução mesmo embora não vi a *query* que preenche ele):

```
SELECT tblA.*, tblB.coluna FROM tabelaA tblA
    INNER JOIN tabelaB tblB ON (tblA.coluna = tblB.coluna)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/WhereInJoin.sql).

Se você vai ter problemas de performance ou não e qual abordagem é melhor, só testando o seu caso. Qualquer informação geral para seu caso específico será especulação, mesmo que seja uma estimativa fundamentada.

A existência de índices adequados pode mudar mais do que a forma da *query*.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode ter problemas de performance sim, mas isso também depende de outros fatores. Não sei de onde vêm os valores que você filtra, mas se vierem de outra tabela pode ser melhor usar um `JOIN` ([como na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53702/57801)) ou uma subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM tabelaA tblA 
WHERE tblA.coluna IN (SELECT id FROM tabelaB WHERE coluna = x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro utilizar exists, select in irá capturar "todos" os dados da consulta filho alocar em memoria e responder ao pai...
Usando exists irá retornar apenas o primeiro registro valido comprovando existência...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html